# Model not getting imported as a Sequelize.Model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use a sequelize N:M relation trough another table but I keep getting this error:

```
throw new Error(${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model);

Error: Cases.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

Here are my classes:

**models/User.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sql = require('../config/sql');
const DocumentType = require('./DocumentType');
const Case = require('./Case');


const User = sql.define('Users', {
    firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    document: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    documentTypeId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
    active: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

User.belongsTo(DocumentType, {foreignKey: 'documentTypeId' ,as: 'documentType'});
User.belongsToMany(Case, { through: 'CaseUser' });

User.findById = (id) => {
    return User.findOne({
        where: {
            id: id
        },
        include: 'documentType'
    });
};

User.findByEmail = (email) => {
    return  User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        },
        include: 'documentType'
    });
};

User.checkActiveStatus = (id) => {
    return User.findOne({
        where: {
            id: id
        },
        attributes: ['active']
    });
};

module.exports = User;
```

**models/Case.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sql = require('../config/sql');
const User = require('./User');

const Case = sql.define('Cases', {
  description: Sequelize.STRING,
  startDate: Sequelize.STRING
});

Case.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'CaseUser'});

module.exports = Case;
```

I get the error only in the `Case.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'CaseUser' });` and not in the `User.belongsToMany(Case, { through: 'CaseUser' });` one

The weird thing is that if I switch the `belongsToMany(User...` for `belongsToMany(DocumentType...` and import the DocumentType file I don't get the error. The DocumentType Model is virtually identical to the User one

**models/DocumentType.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sql = require('../config/sql');

const DocumentType = sql.define('DocumentTypes', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  slug: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
  timestamps: false
});

module.exports = DocumentType;
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid circular dependencies.

1. Remove lines

```
const Case = require('./Case');
```

and

```
Case.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'CaseUser'});
```

from User.js

2. Remove lines

```
const User = require('./User');
```

and

```
User.belongsToMany(Case, { through: 'CaseUser' });
```

from Case.js

3. Create associations.js

```
const Case = require('./Case');
const User = require('./User');

Case.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'CaseUser'});
User.belongsToMany(Case, { through: 'CaseUser' });
```

Comment: How should I handle the associations from that file? Should I import them in one of the models using require?

Comment: You should import all models and associations.js in something like database.js and export sequelize instance with registered models from it in places where you would like to query models via sequelize.

Comment: If I create the file as it is in the comment the same error from before will pop up when I do a require(associations.js) from a model file, where should I import it?